# Magento admin giving 500 error - nothing in logs

Tags: php, magento, error-log

My Magento-admin stopped working after I tried to install a extension. Now I get a 500 error when I try to access the /admin. Strange thing is that nothing shows up in the error_log. Developer mode log:

> Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php on
>   line 7349
>
> #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(7349):
>   mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/vhosts...',
>   7349, Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(7421):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->start('adminhtml') #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(7777):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('core', 'adminhtml') #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(33479):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('core', 'adminhtml') #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(23438):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Session->__construct(Array) #5
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(462):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/session', Array) #6
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(476):
>   Mage::getModel('core/session', Array) #7
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(13658):
>   Mage::getSingleton('core/session', Array) #8
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch() #9
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(13572):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch() #10
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(17928):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') #11
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(17485):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #12
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(20062):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #13
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #14
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/index.php(94): Mage::run('',
>   'store') #15 {main}

Already tried uninstalling the extension, no luck. What should I do to find the cause of the error?

Comment: you should publish your default.php on line 7349 code to get more helpful comments.

Comment: The error you show is only notice . please dig on your server log may help . Example apache errorlog for your vhost or MySQL error log. 500 also could be your .htaccess problem too . the plugin may change it or require some mod in apache to be  open

Comment: The frontend of the shop is working fine. Can it still be a htaccess problem?

Comment: vhost error_log doesn't show any error, same thing with /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: mysqld.log : no errors (concerning this issue) as well

Comment: For some reason, I always get an "Internal; Server Error" whenever I log into my admin page. However, reloading the page clears it and things then work perfectly. I confess to never having investigated the cause as all I have to do is reload to clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, firstly disable compilation, use this:

`php -f your_project_folder/shell/compiler.php clear
 php -f your_project_folder/shell/compiler.php disable`

Then clear cache var/cache. You can just remove this folder.

Comment: This helped a lot! Finally fixed it with a backup though.